# How do I get size of child so I can center it in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to center an absolutely positioned DIV in ReactJS whose textual contents will change.

```
function Center(props) {
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  const offset = -width/2;

  useEffect(() => {
    if(divRef.current) setWidth(divRef.original.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  return <div ref={divRef} style={{left: props.x + offset}}>{props.message}</div>
}
```

I'm stuck on how to get the size of the DIV after the contents of the DIV has changed, so that I can center it by setting the style left/right.

1. I can't hook into `window.onresize` because the size of the DIV has nothing to do with the window size and all to do with the text content.
2. This is a simplified example and the actual example is more complicated, so I cannot use pure CSS layout to center it. I must assign `style.left` in pixels to accomplish it.
3. I can get the width at the initial render, but I need the width to be updated every time the text changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()` [(getBoundingClientRect)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the size of an element.

Edit:
The answer is to add `props.message` to the dependency array of `useEffect`. This will execute the code in useEffect (used to calculate the width) everytime when `props.message` changes instead of only on the initial render. See comments on this answer.

Comment: I'm already using offsetWidth which works, but I can't get the updated value when the textual content changes.

Comment: Could you add `props.message` to your useEffect dependency array and also recalculate offset in useEffect like this  
`useEffect(() => {/*your original code + */ offset = -width/2; }, [props.message])`. It should recalculate the width when the message (textual content) changes.

Comment: Adding the `prop.message` to the dependency worked. I can't believe I missed that. I have marked your answer as correct :) and I suggest you update your answer to include that for future readers understanding.